# plot and volume of y^2+z^2=1 cut by the plane y=x and x=1 in the first quadrant

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, regions, homework

I need to plot and find the volume of y^2+z^2=1 cut by the plane y=x and x=1 in the first quadrant

So far,

```
RegionPlot3D[
    y^2 + z^2 - 1 <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, {z, 0, Sqrt[1 - y^2]}, 
    AxesLabel -> Automatic]
RegionPlot3D[
    y <= x && x <= 1 && z <= Sqrt[1 - y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, {z, 0, 
    Sqrt[1 - y^2]}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

And for volume

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 - y^2], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]
```

Both produce an output I'm sure is incorrect. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Funny title---plot and volume---what about solve and area, integrate and length :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the finite region in the first quadrant of x-y plane is `0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= x`,and the finite region in the space is as below.

```
reg=ImplicitRegion[{y^2 + z^2 <= 1, 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= x}, {x, y, 
   z}] 
reg// Volume
reg//Region
```

> `1/6 (-4 + 3 Pi)`

Comment: `RegionPlot3D[{x, y, z} \[Element] reg, AxesLabel -> Automatic] doesnt seem to work`

Comment: @calcNoob1 Thanks, `RegionPlot3D[reg,AxesLabel -> Automatic]` also work.

Comment: it worked thank you very much :)